Cannot boot Dell Inspiron 3891 using 24.04 LTS: (Noble Numbat) bootable USB drive during installation attempt
First: sincere thanks to @David DE, @Karel, and @Amar for their help and suggestions.
Problem: Cannot boot Dell Inspiron 3891 using 24.04 LTS: (Noble Numbat) bootable USB drive during installation attempt.
Flashed USB drive using Belinaetcher with Ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64(2).iso as instructed by Ubuntu website.
Configured Bios and Installed Ubuntu on my backup computer (ZT desktop) without problems.
Used same procedures on Dell 3891 re-configuring BIOS to boot for Install.
On reboot the Dell displayed the Grub startup menu (Try Ubuntu, etc) but died as soon as the 'Try Ubuntu' option was chosen, presenting a black screen with a tiny non-blinking cursor in top right-hand corner, leaving the computer unresponsive.
I brought up Grub options on later boot attempts, but without a loaded Kernel most of the commands produced errors.
At first I suspected that the USB boot drive, (EUFI SanDisk 3-2 Gen 1 A20044E45BC3F810) might have somehow been corrupted, but used it to Install Ubuntu on Laptop (HP Pavilion dm-4) as a test without any problem.
Returning to the Dell I went through BIOS and tried different settings. For two days. All of them in various combinations with the same failure.
I can usually figure things out with patience and persistence, but this one has me stumped.
Final Dell Bios settings before I gave up:
Boot order Configuration:

EFUI SanDisk SanDisk3.2 Gen1 A20044E45BC3F810   (Ubuntu Bootable USB Drive)
Windows Boot Manager
UEFI Hard Drive

Secure Boot: Off
Secure Boot Mode: Audit Mode  (Performs a signature check but does not block operation of UEFI drivers and Bootloaders
Custom key Mode Management: Set to PK
Integrated Devices:
Enable Audio: On
Enable microphone: On
USB Configuration:
Front, Rear and USB Boot Support: All enabled
SATA Operation:
RAID: On
SATA-0, SATA-1, SATA-3, M.2 PCIe SDD-0, Smart Reporting and Secure Digital Card: All enabled
Network Controller Configuration:
Enabled with PXE
WLan: Enabled
Bluetooth: Disabled
UEFI Network Stack: On
HTTP(s) Boot in Manual Mode
Platform Trust Technology: Off
SIMM Security Mitigation: Off
Data Wipe on Next Boot: Off
Wake on LAN or WAN: Off
Wake on Time: Off
SERR Messages: Off
Preboot Behavior:
Continue on Warnings and Errors: On
UEFI Boot Process: Auto
BIOS Post time: 10 Seconds
Virtualization Support:
Virtualization Technology and VT for Direct I/O: Both On
Multi-Core Support:
All Cores enabled, Speed-Step Technology and C-States Control enabled
Turbo Boost Technology, Hyper-Threading technology: Enabled
UEFI Capsule Firmware Updates: On
BIOS Recovery from Hard Drive: On
Allow BIOS Downgrade: On
Support Assist OS Recovery: On
BIOS Connect: On  (Threshold 2)
